# merge array in deep array nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have the following structure:

```
const array = [
  [
    [
      [
        [
          {
            'name':'John'
          }
        ],
        {
          'name':'Mary'
        }
      ],
      {
        'name':'Cris'
      }
    ],
    {
      'name':'Deen'
    }
  ],
  {
    'name':'Bob'
  }
]
```

And I'd like to get the following structure as a result:

```
const expect = [
  {
    'name':'John'
  },
  {
    'name':'Mary'
  },
  {
    'name':'Cris'
  },
  {
    'name':'Deen'
  },
  {
    'name':'Bob'
  },
]
```

How do I make such conversion with `lodash` or another library?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep

Comment: Why don't you show your efforts ? Where is your code ?

Comment: Not hard to find out how to flatten an array with limited web search time and some digging through lodash docs

Comment: That's *not* merging, that is **flattening**. you confused the terms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`_.flattenDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/#flattenDeep) from lodash:

> Recursively flattens array.

```js
const array = [[[[[{ name: 'John' }], { name: 'Mary' }], { name: 'Cris' }], { name: 'Deen' }], { name: 'Bob' }];
    
console.log(_.flattenDeep(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I never thought I would see this day come O_O!

Comment: @Arrow, what do you mean?

Comment: You used lodash. Enemy to all higher order functions.

Comment: @Arrow, hm. the use does not justify the product.

Comment: @NinaSchotz O_o This is like seeing Superman use a gun. I will be scarred for life.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147533/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-arrow).

Answer (score 1):

You can create recursive function using `reduce()` to return desired result.

```js
const array = [[[[[{"name":"John"}],{"name":"Mary"}],{"name":"Cris"}],{"name":"Deen"}],{"name":"Bob"}]

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
     return r = r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? flatten(e) : e), r
  }, [])
}

console.log(flatten(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this npm package [npm underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore-node) and this is a simple example:

`var _ = require('underscore-node');
var extractedArray = _.flatten(deepArray)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function flattenArray(array, result) {
    result = result || [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            flattenArray(array[i], result);
        } else {
            result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I wrote this some time back. Follows a recursive approach and is really fast as well.

JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/flatten-array-r1

Answer (score 0):

By pure ES6 and a Haskellesque pattern matching implemented by destructuring, you may simply do as follows;

```js
function flat([a,...b]){
  return (Array.isArray(a) ? flat(a) : [a]).concat(b.length ? flat(b) : []);
}

var arr = [[[[[{"name":"John"}],{"name":"Mary"}],{"name":"Cris"}],{"name":"Deen"}],{"name":"Bob"}],
    res = flat(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with closures and a single line of code with ES6. Libraries, when not necessary are a burden. Avoid them where you can.

```js
const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((r, e) => (r = r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? flatten(e) : e), r), []);

const array = [
  [
    [
      [
        [{
          'name': 'John'
        }],
        {
          'name': 'Mary'
        }
      ],
      {
        'name': 'Cris'
      }
    ],
    {
      'name': 'Deen'
    }
  ],
  {
    'name': 'Bob'
  }
];
console.log(flatten(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Optimal way without any library and using good-old JS logic:

```js
var arr = [
  [
    [
      [
        [
          {
            'name':'John'
          }
        ],
        {
          'name':'Mary'
        }
      ],
      {
        'name':'Cris'
      }
    ],
    {
      'name':'Deen'
    }
  ],
  {
    'name':'Bob'
  }
];

// convert to string and remove all Array "[" and "]" symbols
var str = JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\[|]/g,'');
// convert the String back to an Object (Array)
var flatArr = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");

console.log(flatArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful for doing in memory data structure processing (once you wrap your head around it).

Here is how you could solve your example

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  reverse: false,
  rtn: 'value',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => typeof value.name === 'string'
})(input);

const array = [[[[[{ name: 'John' }], { name: 'Mary' }], { name: 'Cris' }], { name: 'Deen' }], { name: 'Bob' }];

console.log(find(array));
// => [ { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Mary' }, { name: 'Cris' }, { name: 'Deen' }, { name: 'Bob' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)